# Slow query performance in postgres function that returns a set of records via return query execute

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, stored-functions

I have a function that uses a few parameters and returns a set of records. The function doesn't do anything other than run a query, which needs to be contained in the function so that my application layer can do some introspection magic on it, (I'm using [PostGraphile](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/)).

On its own, the query is quite quick scanning a few million records and making heavy use of some distance operators, (primarily `<->>`), and their corresponding indexes. As a function, the query is significantly slower, (~20s up from ~600ms). Other answers I've seen suggested uses dynamic SQL to avoid having my query plan cached which I've done, but I had to use `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE ...` to run it because I am returning a set of rows.

## Current Approach

The result function is structured like this, query removed for brevity:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_nearby(
  term text,
  user_location json,
  distance integer,
  result_limit integer = 100,
  result_offset integer = 0
)
  RETURNS SETOF nearby_results_table
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
  DECLARE
    sql text := 'big complicated query for searching things nearby';
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql USING term, user_location, distance, result_limit, result_offset;
END
$function$;
```

This runs very slowly. Below are some other approaches I've tried.

## Return output

This approach proves that the query *can* be quick, but it doesn't actually return anything:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_nearby(
  term text,
  user_location json,
  distance integer,
  result_limit integer = 100,
  result_offset integer = 0
)
  RETURNS SETOF nearby_results_table
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
  DECLARE
    output nearby_results_table%rowtype;
    sql text := 'big complicated query for searching things nearby';
BEGIN
EXECUTE sql INTO output USING term, user_location, distance, result_limit, result_offset;
END
$function$;
```

This runs in the expected ~600ms, but obviously doesn't return anything. Based on this, I am assuming that using `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE ...` is somehow still using a cached query plan. Adding `RETURN output;` to the function yields an error, which is why I need to use the `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE ...` approach, *I think*: `RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set`

## The query itself

I'm simplifying a bit here, but this is essentially the query:

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  label,
  location,
  label <->> $search_term as match,
  ST_DISTANCE(location, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON($search_location)) as distance
FROM things
WHERE ST_DISTANCE(location, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON($search_location)) < 5000
AND label <->> $search_term < .5
ORDER BY match, distance
LIMIT 100
```

Hopefully, there is an obvious mistake in the construction of the function; but, I'd be happy to set up a fiddle if exact reproduction is necessary for the diagnosis.

Some immovable requirements:

1. This must be a function so that PostGraphile can introspect it
2. It must return a set of an actual table because the table has foreign keys defined in it, (the table is empty, I'm literally just using it to define the return structure of this function)

---

## Update

### Function

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_nearby_shops_and_inventory(
  term text,
  user_location json,
  distance integer,
  result_limit integer = 100,
  result_offset integer = 0
)
  RETURNS SETOF search_nearby_shop_and_inventory_result
  LANGUAGE sql
  STABLE
AS $function$
SELECT
    null as inventory_id,
    id as shop_id,
    store.name,
    store.name <->> term as match,
    st_distance(store.geolocation, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(user_location)) as distance,
    'store' as result_type
from store
where store.name <->> term < .5
union
select
  inventory.id as inventory_id,
  null as shop_id,
  product.name as name,
  product.name <->> term as match,
  st_distance(store.geolocation, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(user_location)) as distance,
  'inventory' as result_type
from product
join inventory on product.id = product_id
join store on store_id = store.id
where st_distance(store.geolocation, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(user_location)) < distance
and store.active = true
and product.name <->> term < .5
order by match, distance
limit result_limit
offset result_offset;
$function$;
```

### Explain

```
Limit  (cost=3865336.61..3865336.86 rows=100 width=108) (actual time=20913.060..20913.062 rows=9 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=97166, temp read=77 written=77
  ->  Sort  (cost=3865336.61..3865653.31 rows=126678 width=108) (actual time=20913.059..20913.060 rows=9 loops=1)
        Sort Key: ((store.name <->> 'red scissors'::text)), (st_distance(store.geolocation, '0101000020E61000003AAC1512D59B5EC04E9DA27E72E14240'::geography, true))
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
        Buffers: shared hit=97166, temp read=77 written=77
        ->  Unique  (cost=3858278.20..3860495.07 rows=126678 width=108) (actual time=20913.039..20913.050 rows=9 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=97166, temp read=77 written=77
              ->  Sort  (cost=3858278.20..3858594.90 rows=126678 width=108) (actual time=20913.038..20913.039 rows=9 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: (NULL::uuid), store.id, store.name, ((store.name <->> 'red scissors'::text)), (st_distance(store.geolocation, '0101000020E61000003AAC1512D59B5EC04E9DA27E72E14240'::geography, true)), ('store'::text)
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=97166, temp read=77 written=77
                    ->  Append  (cost=0.00..3840177.73 rows=126678 width=108) (actual time=91.555..20913.009 rows=9 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=97166, temp read=77 written=77
                          ->  Seq Scan on store  (cost=0.00..162580.87 rows=6313 width=99) (actual time=91.554..115.831 rows=2 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((name <->> 'red scissors'::text) < '0.5'::double precision)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 18937
                                Buffers: shared hit=4462
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=545955.17..3675696.69 rows=120365 width=126) (actual time=15487.818..20797.169 rows=7 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (product.id = inventory.product_id)
                                Buffers: shared hit=92704, temp read=77 written=77
                                ->  Seq Scan on product  (cost=0.00..94012.04 rows=780512 width=66) (actual time=3.809..20158.989 rows=1412 loops=1)
                                      Filter: ((name <->> 'red scissors'::text) < '0.5'::double precision)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 2340130
                                      Buffers: shared hit=58889
                                ->  Hash  (cost=537562.47..537562.47 rows=361096 width=64) (actual time=631.191..631.191 rows=5152 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 65536  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 543kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=33809, temp written=44
                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=478203.70..537562.47 rows=361096 width=64) (actual time=43.640..627.793 rows=5152 loops=1)
                                            Hash Cond: (inventory.store_id = store_1.id)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=33809
                                            ->  Seq Scan on inventory  (cost=0.00..53117.59 rows=2377059 width=48) (actual time=0.012..356.725 rows=2377065 loops=1)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=29347
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=478167.74..478167.74 rows=2877 width=48) (actual time=42.962..42.963 rows=32 loops=1)
                                                  Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 35kB
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=4462
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on store store_1  (cost=0.00..478167.74 rows=2877 width=48) (actual time=0.310..42.914 rows=32 loops=1)
                                                        Filter: (active AND (st_distance(geolocation, '0101000020E61000003AAC1512D59B5EC04E9DA27E72E14240'::geography, true) < '5000'::double precision))
                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 18907
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=4462
Planning Time: 0.688 ms
Execution Time: 20913.122 ms
```

Comment: First, use an SQL function rather than a PL/pgSQL function. Collect `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the slow query and add it to the question.

Comment: Why use dynamic SQL and PL/pgSQL at all, if you just want to run a query? And a function running a query should never be declared `immutable` but `stable`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the tip. Storing this as a function makes my application layer significantly simpler; I'd like to keep the logic of this query separated from that layer.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Done and done!

Comment: @cazzer: I do understand that, but dynamic SQL is complete overkill for that (and PL/pgSQL probably as well)